# Upload a System.Drawing.Bitmap without saving to disk first

Tags: c#

I have a System.Drawing.Bitmap which needs to uploaded to a server, all this is working fine except I'm writing the image to disk, uploading the image on disk, then finally deleting it. Is there a way to do this without saving to disk first and upload it from memory? The code I'm currently using looks something like this.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(someX, someY);
//code to create my image
bmp.Save("c:\sometempfile.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadFile(urlToUploadTo, "POST", "c:\sometempfile.jpeg");
System.IO.File.Delete("c:\sometempfile.jpeg");
```

Comment: Hint: An overload of  `bmp.Save` takes a `Stream`. There's a special kind of `Stream` which is called a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. I haven't tested it, so that's up to you, but basically you should write the bitmap to a memorystream, after which you can write that stream to your webclient's target URL via the desired HTTP method.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);    
    using (var postStream = client.OpenWrite(endpointUrl))
    {
        memoryStream.CopyTo(postStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the line which reads the file, there's no file to read from anymore.

Comment: Tnx, that wasn't very useful indeed :).